# When exactly setter function is ES6 class is called, when we use the same name for the name of the setter as the name of the property?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, es6-class

Since yesterday I am wondering when exactly the setter method for fullName is being called by JS behind the scenes?

I was trying to figure it out on my own, but i could not. I know, that it happens, when we write `this.fullName = fullName` but how? this.fullName is  undefined before 3rd line, so when we set it,  fullName, before calling "this.fullName" is equal to the argument, that we pass in.

After the instruction `this.fullName = fullName` this.fullName is equal to the passed argument, and fullName is still this argument passed to a constructor.. So when and how this setter is called? How does JS know, that it should call the setter, and not just simply assign argument to a variable?

```
class PersonCL {

  constructor(fullName, birthYear) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.birthYear = birthYear;
  }

  set fullName(name) {
    if (name.includes(' ')) this._fullName = name;
    else alert(`${name} is not a full name!`);
  }

  get fullName() {
    return this._fullName;
  }  

}
```

Comment: Okay, sorry and thank You very much for your changes! I will remember to write better next time! I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a getter and/or setter of a class property, this is implemented as a property descriptor in the class prototype. The property is defined something like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(PersonCL.prototype, 'fullName', {
    set: function(name) {
        if (name.includes(' ')) this._fullName = name;
        else alert(`${name} is not a full name!`);
    },
    get: function() {
        return this._fullName;
    }  
});
```

This is done when the class definition is executed. When a class instance is created, it inherits from the prototype, so the descriptor is inherited. The `set` function is called when the constructor assigns to `this.fullName`.

See the MDN documentation of [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: I think OP is confused because the getters and setters are defined "after" the constructor when actually the getters and setters are created before the constructor is called?

Comment: I've added an explanation of the timing.

Comment: I actually come from Java background, so I do not have problem with understanding OOP principles, and way of work. The only thing which is weird for me, is the implementation in JS, but I know, its not typical OOP with classic classes and inheritance, it has prototypal inheritance instead.

Thank for your respond Barmar! So when we have setter in our ES6 class, named exactly the same as one of the object properties, then when we assign value to this property, the setter is called, right?

Comment: If you use the `class` syntax, you can practically ignore prototypal inheritance, it acts just like classic OOP.

Comment: Yes I know, but I just want to clearly understand what is going on and how things happen in the background. I want to clearly understand the difference, so I can explain it to someone, who asks me. And besides that I am just really curious and not only I want to know, how to do something, but also know, how it is happening.

Comment: The implementation uses property descriptors in the class prototype.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show the underlying implementation with a property descriptor.